# NTFS Advanced Deny permissions and Rules

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, ntfs

I feel like I am missing something obvious here. Or just making a noob mistake.

I have a folder structure as shown in the example below. Folder `A1` and `A2` are inside folder `A`. Folders `B1`, `B2` are inside folder `A1` and so on.

```
Folder A
|
|
|
|--------Folder A1
|          |---------Folder B1
|          |---------Folder B2
|--------Folder A2
|          |---------Folder C1
|          |---------Folder C2
```

I want to create a  group permission on folder `A` that prevents users from creating, deleting or moving a file or folder inside of it (i.e. they can't move or delete A1 and A2, etc.), but not affect anything in Folder `A1` or `A2`.

I created the following rules on Folder `A`
Group A (the one i want to limit).

Rule:

```
Name: Group A
Apply to: this folder and subfolders
    Deny Create files / write data
    Deny Create Folders / append data
    Deny Delete subfolders and files
    Deny Delete

Checkmarked: Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container only.
```

Rule:

```
Name: Group A
Apply to: This folder, subfolders and files
Allow everything but Full Control, Delete, change permissions, take ownership

NOT checkmarked: Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container only.
```

I know many people are against the use of `Deny` permissions because of the fact it can easily override all others. etc. But I don't feel intelligently set up `Deny` rules should be ignored as a non option.

Now the actual problem occurs inside Folders `B1`, `B2`, etc.

Inside `B1`, `B2`, `C1`, etc. I can delete folders/files and move folders inside of other folders. I can't however create folders or files. I also can't move folders into folders `B1`, `B2`, etc. (Even though I can them move out).

When I check the permission on the folders inside of `A1` or `A2` I see nothing wrong. When I check the permissions ON `A1`, `A2` from `A` I see the rules only apply to THIS folder and not SUBFOLDERS.

A Microsoft Article (*TechNet: [Selecting where to apply permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776140(v=ws.10).aspx)*) says that when I checkmark `"Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this"` the rules should only apply to subfolders within Folder `A` and not subsequent folders.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Note: I tried multiple methods including not using `Deny` or any kind of implicit rules.

Comment: This is really hard to read/follow. I don't know how you can fix it, but consider giving it a look and seeing how you might make it less of a WALL OF TEXT and streamline what you're trying to get to.

Comment: @MDMarra: I tried to reformat the post a bit. (I am not the original author.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to break permission inheritance at A and remove the default Users ACL (or maybe not, up to you).

Create an ACL on Folder `A` for Group `A` that applies to "This Folder Only" and set it to Read.

Create another ACL on Folder `A` for Group `A` that applies to "Subfolders Only and Files" and set it to Modify (or whatever you  want).

This will make it so that people in group `A` cannot change the folder structure *directly* below A, but can modify anything at a lower level.

---

As for this:

> When I check the permission on the folders inside of A1 or A2 I see nothing wrong. When I check the permissions ON A1, A2 from A I see the rules only apply to THIS folder and not SUBFOLDERS.

Sounds like someone broke inheritance and propagated a different ACL throughout that subfolder structure. You should fix that so that everything below Folder `A` inherits from Folder `A`.

Also, in the future, using a folder names the same as a group in your example makes it a little hard for others to follow :)